# Best Way to Encrypt Customer Information in My Company's MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

So long story short, our company recently had an intrusion wherein our MySQL DB was dumped and stolen. The execs are really nervous now and in addition to upping other security measures, they are intent on encrypting all customer information (email address, home address, names, and the like) in the DB.

I am unsure of where to begin on this. We run a PHP app. Obviously, this is going to create some additional overhead that we'd like to minimize. Another concern is going to be the difficulty in changing the code wherever the new encrypted fields are used.

This strikes me as an unnecessary precaution, but management seems firm on it.

What type of encryption algorithm/method would be best for this use case?

Comment: Beef up your server security. Spend the time there. It seems really extreme to encrypt all data. Push back, the suits don't know everything.

Comment: First two results in google for "AES php" http://www.phpaes.com/ http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php

Comment: Your database access should be isolated to the point where a low-level change in your models is all that is required to encrypt the data. Literally nothing outside of your data layer/models/business objects should have to change, or even be aware that the data is encrypted. If you have to change the way the model is being used because its internal storage changes, your app is very poorly written.

Comment: It might benefit you to give more information about how the data was stolen in the first place.  Is it a coding issue?  Is it a server-setup issue?  Sensitive data is best put on a separate server that can only be accessed by white-listed machines using encryption.  Look up salts and hashing.

Comment: @Paul I definitely agree with you there, but I'm pretty low in the chain of command. My project manager asked me to look into viable options for encrypting all sensitive customer info. Perhaps I need to come up with some way to show the higher-ups that what they want is unnecessary and hackish?

Comment: @earthmeLon "Salts and hashing" has nothing to do with this question, *at all*. "Throw salts and hashes at it" != security, and you shouldn't suggest it if you don't know what it is.

Comment: Your question implies that the hacker has access to your internal systems and DB. You must decide what you really need - either make your bosses happy for another month or two, or implement a good corporate security.

Comment: @eysikal I hear you. I'd start by showing them this thread.

Comment: @earthmeLon Yes, it certainly doesn't help our cause from the IT end that we don't know how our data was compromised. We suspect it was an exploit/security hole in some of the blogging or forum software that we run on our site.

Comment: @meagar I am very familiar with salts and hashing.  As I stated, his intents and his problems are not clear to me.  I am trying to give the user some key words that he or she can use to research more information on securing databases and information.  salting/hashing is very useful information for adding security to stored information.

Comment: @eysikal There is nothing "unnecessary and hackish" about encrypting customer data. It is *absolutely* necessary, and required by law depending on where you do business. It's completely irresponsible for you to *not already be doing this*.

Comment: @eysikal I bet you guys have root mysql open to password-less login from localhost?  This is the kind of stuff that results in information theft.

Comment: @earthmeLon Again, salts and hashing are not remotely applicable here, even as keywords. He's not talking about securely storing passwords, he's talking about storing "email address, home address, names" using *reversible encryption*. If you want useful keywords, try "[securing PII](https://www.google.com/?q=securing+PII)". The secure storage of [Personally Identifiable Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) is a **huge** deal, and one that should have been addressed before you ever started storing your customer's data.

Comment: @meagar The really sensitive stuff like user passwords are one-way encrypted. We do not store payment information. Is it common to encrypt names, addresses and the like? If it's "completely irresponsible" to leave these types of fields unencrypted, then I'm gonna go ahead and guess that 80% of web apps our there are "irresponsible."

Comment: @eysikal Look into mysql injections.  You have to sanitize/normalize all user input.  This includes _POST,_GET, AND COOKIES.  Don't forget those nasty cookies.  mysql_real_escape_string();

Comment: @meagar I agree with you on the model thing. Unfortunately, as you well realize, we do not always get to work on projects where everything is done correctly. There is a form of separation view/model/db logic present in the app, but it's not perfect. There are plenty of "rouge" queries out there that don't follow this paradigm that we'll have to hunt down.

Comment: @eysikal Encrypting data will do nothing if you don't compartmentalize your system.  ie:  If I gain access to your server with your database, then you need to make sure I don't have access to any encryption keys.    Something about eggs and baskets and not letting them all get destroyed at once :P

Comment: @eysikal Not only is it common, as I've said it is very likely [required by law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information#In_privacy_law) if you do business in North America. Ignorance is not an excuse, and "everybody else does it" is not an excuse. You guys could be in huge legal trouble if it is discovered that your data was compromised and PII was stolen.

Comment: @meagar - So, when I access Facebooks API and gather thousands of user's person info, your suggesting that's illegal? the PII "law" you're referring to means that you need to secure info such as SSN's CC info etc. not basic stuff

Comment: I'm nominating this question be re-opened because new questions are being closed as a duplicate of this one and there's a better answer that can be provided.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is a very good writeup on how to do this with MySQL here: http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/.

You'll want to use AES with 256bit keys, as that is the prevailing best-practice/standard right now. 256bit AES keys are considered to be of sufficient size to be secure against modern computing power.

It's a good idea, regardless of if you think it's overkill or not, to encrypt your database. Even if the data isn't horribly sensitive, the loss of customer records can be very embarrassing to your company, at the very least, and could adversely affect customer confidence and people's willingness to hand over their data in the future. Encrypting the full contents of your database may not be industry-standard right now but trends are moving that way and it cannot hurt you to adopt a stronger security posture. If nothing else, think of it as another entry in your Defense-In-Depth implementation.

I would also recommend you check this article out - http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/secure-mysql-database-design - as it provides a good, fairly basic, introduction to secure database system design that should give you some pointers on other things to check for your application.

Comment: This method is not very secure, because the encryption mode will be droped back to the **unsafed ECB mode** with this kind of approach.