# Best way to encrypt and decrypt data using php and mysql

Tags: algorithm, encryption

To start, I am trying to encrypt very sensitive information on a public website. Users will be able to update their information, Administrators will need access to this information. I am worried that if the encrypted data is some how compromised, then everyone's information would be as well due to them all using the same salt and key.

So I know using a salt, and key is always preferred. But as mentioned above if they reverse engineer the encrypted data, what use it is.

My solution, is to have the key and salt stored in a DB, with many rows and columns, any of which can be used for the salt or key. I would have an algorithm that will use "something" fixed in the users account that will be used to figure out which salt and key to use. This way statistically speaking no 2 years will have same combo of salt and key.

Is this over kill, or good?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265877/best-way-to-encrypt-customer-information-in-my-companys-mysql-db) which, although closed, has a highly-rated and accepted answer. See also [this Server Fault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/538715/whats-a-good-way-to-encrypt-a-mysql-database-and-is-it-worth-it), and [this one](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39027/building-a-web-app-with-encrypted-mysql-database-entries). In general, don't try to re-invent security code. Depend on stuff written by people smarter than you.

Comment: You realize the house lock has been around for over 100 years. With that logic, lets not reinvent a new house lock. With that said, Give me a 5 dollar lock picking set, 10 minutes, and I will have your house unlocked for you. I appreciate the feed back on the links you sent, but I was wondering if there was any credence to my new logic for added security. The stackexchange was the closest article, but the problem there was the derived key was a known field which was from the password, which also meant if the user changes his password he would need to re-encrypt all the data.

Comment: The way I read your question, you are considering implementing a new and unproven encryption method to use in a critical application to protect very sensitive information. I caution strongly against that and suggest that you instead look to see what others are using. There are many high-profile sites that use existing methods to good effect. Now, if you're proposing a new way of encrypting and securing highly sensitive data, then more power to you. But be very wary about using it in a production application without extensive testing and peer review.

Answer (score 1):

I question the value of this second database that holds keys and salts. Consider:

- The "something" in the user's data that identifies the salt and key will necessarily have to be encrypted differently from the rest of the user's data. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to get it without first already having it.
- Statistical analysis of the encrypted user data would almost certainly discover that the "something" is encrypted differently. That will be like waving a red flag at a bull, and an attacker will concentrate on figuring out why that's different.
- You can assume that if an attacker can get the database of encrypted user information, he can also get the database of salts and keys.

Given that, there are two possible scenarios:

1. The encryption of the "something" that identifies the key and salt is unbreakable. That is, it's so good that the attacker's best efforts fail to reveal the connection between that "something" and the key/salt database.
2. The attacker discovers the encryption of the "something," and therefore is able to decrypt your sensitive data.

If #1 is the case, then you probably should use that encryption algorithm for *all* of your user data. Why do something in two steps when you can do it just as effectively in one?

If #2 is the case, then all the work you've done just put up a little bump in the road for the attacker.

So, short answer: what you propose looks like either unnecessary work or ineffective road blocking. In either case, it looks to me like a whole lot of work and added complexity for no appreciable gain.

That said, I could have misinterpreted your brief description. If so, please correct me.

Comment: here is my point, If we know, we need to add a salt and a key to the algorithm. Why not make the salt and the key unique(ish ( theoretical 2 years may have same key and salt combo but very unlikely)). I want to have a table of prelisted keys and salts, where some algorythm will determine which salt and which key to use.  So unless the attacker go to the file system and looked at the algorythm, there isnt any easy way decrypt the info, because if the attacker got 5... or 10 sets of data, and tried to reverse engineer the equation using that, there would be no way to do so.

Comment: If the attacker got access to the file system, then I'm screwed anyway. If the attacker got access to the DB, they would see 100's of different cells of random text. I did some quick math, there are about 6760000 different possibly key and salt combo's. I figured better then everyone using same key etc. And yes, its just an extra layer for an attacker to have to break. Hope by then, my security system would detect the possible intruder.